# Laravel Lumen Many to One return []

Tags: php, json, database, laravel, lumen

I'm quite new in Lumen but I have to do this because i have final task about Laravel.

So, i do have these two tables, the users and userTypes table.

usertypes table

```
+-----------------------+
| userTypeId | typeName |
+-----------------------+
| 1          | admin    |
| 2          | buyer    |
| 3          | store    |
+-----------------------+
```

users table

```
+----------------------------------+
| id | name | email   | userTypeId |
+----------------------------------+
| 1  | john | e@e.com | 2          |
+----------------------------------+
```

Now, what i was hoping the output for is something like this:

```
{
  "data" : {
     "id" : 1,
     "nama" : "john",
     "email" : "e@e.com",
     "usertypes" : {
           "typesName" : "buyer"
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried hasMany() and hasOne() and more but the "userTypes" field still return []. Here's the model for both of that.

User.php

```
....
public function usertype() {
   return $this->hasMany(UserTypes::class, 'userTypeId');
}
....
```

UserTypes.php

```
.....
public function User() {
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
.....
```

And here's the UserController.php

```
...
public function user($id) {
   $user = User::with(['usertype'])->findOrFail($id);
   return response()->json(['data' => $user]);
}
...
```

Any way to fix this? I appreciated for anyone who willing to help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that i'm not fully understand the meaning of the "third parameters" and thanks to someone in telegram group that helping me out, in the User model it should be:

```
return $this->hasOne(UserTypes::class, 'userTypeId', 'userTypeId');
```

and it works. Second parameter is the foreign key on the users table, third parameter is the primary column name in that userTypes table. Hope it clears the dumb newbie like me.

[image: it works!]

Answer (score 0):

```
Its better to use find method you use route model binding. when you pass id 
to method User $user auto find user from databse. now we have $user so we 
call relation $user->usertype.
public function user(User $user) {
return response()->json(['data' => $user->usertype]);
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But somehow it doesn't work cause i have passing other variable too like, public function user($truckid), from the route $route->get(user/mytruck/{$truckid});. Also, i think it's because i already defined User in use App\User;, maybe i don't know. Thanks for the tip tho.